# iCloud Drive: NSDocument.revert(toContentsOf:ofType:) called when document is merely opened on another device

Tags: cocoa, icloud, nsdocument, uidocument, icloud-drive

I have a macOS and iOS app, based on `NSDocument` and `UIDocument` respectively.

They synchronize their documents via iCloud Drive.

I noticed that `NSDocument.revert(toContentsOf:ofType:)` is called on the Mac when a document is merely opened in the iOS app:

1. Open the Mac app and open a document in iCloud Drive
2. Open the same document with the iOS app
3. `NSDocument.revert(toContentsOf:ofType:)` is called in the Mac app causing it to reload its contents unnecessarily, since the file contents have not been changed.

I observed that the file's content access date and attribute modification dates change upon opening (`NSURLAttributeModificationDateKey`, `NSURLContentAccessDateKey`).

The documentation says:

**NSDocument.revert(toContentsOf:ofType:)**

*Discards all unsaved document modifications and replaces the document’s contents by reading a file or file package located by a URL of a specified type.*

It seems quite unnecessary to discard all unsaved changes and replacing the document's contents when the contents did not change.

Is it intended behavior to revert a document's contents when only the file attributes change or did I miss anything?